# Why do we need to 'estimate' the PSD

Tags: power-spectral-density, periodogram

I've read about the PSD of one OFDM symbol for instance being an estimate of the PSD, but how can it be an 'estimate', when it literally is the PSD of that OFDM symbol.

What *is* actually being estimated? I get that the OFDM symbol is supposed to be a single record of a WSS random process, and therefore its an estimate of the PSD of the random process because you can't calculate the expected value. But why would you want to calculate the PSD of 'the random process' and not just a single OFDM symbol – surely that's the granularity of focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why would you want to calculate the PSD of 'the random process' and not just a single OFDM symbol – surely that's the granularity of focus.

Because you usually don't care about the single symbol as much as you care about making statements on e.g. the channel in general. So, you estimate the PSD.

Comment: When you say the channel in general do you mean a prolonged period of transmission of symbols over the channel, I.e. it's in the context of some modulation scheme as well as the channel

Comment: well, as you say, the PSD is a property of a stochastic process, not just of a realization. So, that's what we model the channel: a stochastic process. For how long a PSD estimation remains "useful" is up to our model of the stochastic process, so, no, not really for a prolonged period, but as model of the channel.

Comment: I was being confused by the fact that it's the channel that's modelled and you are estimating the PSD _of the channel_, instead of the signal in the channel, but I realised that they're the same thing... By the channel you mean what's in the channel (any noise / signals) at a point in time